# Save PayStack paymentDetails array to a laravel order table

Tags: php, laravel

So, basically, i am using unicodevelopers paystack package to integrate payments in my laravel app. However, when i get payment datails, i am trying to save the array to my Order table by running the code:

```
public function handleGatewayCallback()
    {

        $paymentDetails = Paystack::getPaymentData();

        Order::create([
            'name' => $paymentDetails->orderName,
            'id' => $paymentDetails->orderID,
            'email' => $paymentDetails->email,
            'amount' => $paymentDetails->amount
        ]);
```

However, its throwing a Trying to get property of non object model. I will really appreciate guidiance as this is my first time working with this package.

Here[Thats my array picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QunBF.png)

Comment: According to your array you should access the variable like this $paymentDetails->data->order_id;

Comment: Will try that out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? If yes then show me, how you accessing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

Try this:

```
 Order::create([
        'name' => $paymentDetails['data']['order_id'],
        'id' => $paymentDetails['data']['order_id'],
        'email' => $paymentDetails['data']['customer']['email'],
        'amount' => $paymentDetails['data']['amount']
    ]);
```

check the array content from

> `dd($paymentDetails)`